# called object 'strn' is not a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, compiler-errors

While compiling the below code, i am getting error

> "called object strn is not a function"

tired of this error !! need a solution!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define num 400
int main()
{
    char strn[num];
    int count;
    int a=0,e=0,i=0,o=0,u=0;
    printf("enter your string!\n");
    gets(strn);
    for(count=0;count<strlen(strn);count++)
    {
        if ( strn(count)=='a' )
        {
            a++;
        }
        if (strn(count)=='e')
        {
            e++;
        }
```

Comment: You need `[` and `]` instead of `(` and `)` here: `strn(count)` and use `fgets` instead of `gets`. `gets` is dangerous as it dosen't prevent buffer overflows

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use `strn` as if it's a function: `strn(count)`.

You are presumably trying to access the value at the `count` index, so you should use `strn[count]`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite indicative. You have declared `strn` as an array of characters.

```
char strn[num];
```

And using it as `strn(count)` which is wrong. The compiler considers it as a function. You should use square brackets `[` `]` instead of parentheses `(` `)`.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `strn(count)` *represents* a function call to `strn()` with one argument `count`. What you need is to use the `Array subscripting` operator `[]`, not `()`

You need to change

```
strn(count)
```

to

```
strn[count]
```

Also, please consider using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) over `gets()`.

Answer (score 2):

The subscript operator uses symbols `[]` for enclosing index. So for example instead of

```
strn(count)=='a'
```

you have to write

```
strn[count]=='a'
```

Also function `gets` is not supported any more by the C Standard because it is an unsafe function. Use instead `fgets`.

The program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define num 400

int main( void )
{
    char strn[num];
    char *p;
    int a = 0, e = 0, i = 0, o = 0, u = 0;

    printf( "Enter your string: " );
    fgets( strn, num, stdin );

    for ( p = strn; *p != '\0'; ++p )
    {
        char c = tolower( *p );

        switch ( c )
        {
        case 'a':    
            a++;
            break;
        case 'e':
            e++;
            break;
        // and so on...
```